# Npgsql CREATE USER using ExcuteNonQuery parameter

Tags: c#, npgsql

Hi I am trying to use `SQL CREATE USER` with `NpgsqlParameter` (to prevent *sql injection*):

```
var p = new NpgsqlParameter("p1", "testuser");

using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("CREATE USER @p1", (NpgsqlConnection)sqlConn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I get a run time error

> syntax error at or near $1

Can anyone help me out please?

Comment: Alas, you can't use *binding variables* within `CREATE USER`; add quotation marks, i.e. `"CREATE USER '{userName.Replace("'", "''")}'"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alas, you can't use *binding variables* with `CREATE USER`. To prevent sql injection use *quotation*: `"me; delete from myTable"` -> `"'me; delete from myTable'"`:

```
string userName = ...

using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(
  $"CREATE USER '{userName.Repace("'", "''")}'", 
    (NpgsqlConnection)sqlConn)) {

  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Here we double each apostrophe which is within `userName` and then wrap chnaged name into apostrophes